# How can I programmatically refresh Visual Studio WPF designers?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, automation

Is it possible to programmatically refresh WPF designer windows in Visual Studio e.g. using DTE?

I have some design-time behaviour where I would like to refresh WPF designer windows after file system changes I have detected.

I have tried:

```
dte.ItemOperations.OpenFile(file) //where file is a xaml file
```

but this has no effect.

**Update**

I am looking for a solution where I do not close and then re-open the xaml file, as this is too heavy-handed. I'm looking for a way of getting WPF designers to reload\refresh as they do when the solution is rebuilt.

Answer (score 1):

The best that i can think of is

```
dte.ActiveDocument.Close(vsSaveChanges.vsSaveChangesNo);
dte.ItemOperations.OpenFile(FileName);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's what I'm really trying to avoid as it's a bit heavy-handed.